# Change selected value in dropdown list if session variable exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I've got an html table of attendees with a drop down at the top with three values which filters out VIP, general or show all. This works perfectly, my issue is when a user clicks on a record in the table they going to a modal and after closing the modal the page is refreshed.

I stored a cookie variable and selected the value when the drop down is draw but applying because it's looking for a change evente. How can I change the drop down with javascript after the window has loaded?

```
<select id="ea_constrain" name="ea_constrain" class="blackM" style="width:100px;height:20px;">
    <option value="0">Show All</option>
    <option value="1" >Attending</option>
    <option value="2">VIP</option>
</select>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("select#ea_constrain option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == <cfoutput>"#cookie.attendeeconstraint#"</cfoutput>; 
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: show us your code?

Comment: I would recommend using a cookie rather than a session variable. Session variables are bad juju because if your web application is ever intended to run in a farm, sticky sessions would need to be implemented to ensure that the user remains on the same server per session. This would, of course, reduce the effectiveness of load balancing.

Comment: Good idea Jim! Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways (jQuery):

**Page load**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //code here after page load
})
```

**Event trigger**

```
$('.dropdown').bind('change', function(){
 //code to trigger event
})
```

Comment: Thanks Rui but the window.onload is triggering the function call. I just need to know how to change the value of the drop down without another event.

Comment: $("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue");